# is tencent (video) doing something nasty in iframes?

Tags: iframe, hyperlink

On some websites (hosted on servers within China) I am displaying some tencent videos in iframes. Tencent video is a similar service like youtube but works in China.

to display a video on your website you get a little code snipped similar like this:

```
<div class="video-container"><iframe class="video" src="https://v.qq.com/txp/iframe/player.html?vid=XXXXXXXXXX" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe></div>
```

If I now open the frontend of the website and the video iframe is displayed I can see the following error in the console:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:11066/getversionjpg?hash=YYYYY net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

For me it looks like "within th iframe" it is testet, if on Port 11066 "localhost" answers to a request for a file which was hashed to a a number. Are they checking if a user is registered? or actually checking if someone is logged in? Or what kind of browser player is workinig? are they checkiing on "their localhost"? That does not make sense, or? but to do on the hosting webserver (where I am hosting the website) makes no sense either. So not on the visitor's client, or? Is tencent video doing this "accidently"? I can't believe that.

Or is tencent doing something nasty here?

Can anyone explain what probably is going on here?

Comment: Hi @jagottsicher - have you consider looking at what the URL does - e.g. use `curl` to grab a copy of it (without any _processing_ happening on it) ... for instance `curl -v -o - "https://v.qq.com/txp/iframe/player.html?vid=XXXXXXXXXX"` .. the output shows what is put into the frame...  it's got some content and then some JS that does something for the frame ...

Comment: Technically, this is not a good question for StackOverflow, but it is really interesting.